# Forces and energy expenditure during running

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, power

I would like to understand which forces do work during running, to estimate the related energy expenditure. For a bird flying at a constant speed $V$, it's clear that lift $L$ doesn't do any work, and all the energy expenditure is due to drag $D$, which has to be overcome by thrust $T$, which does work at a rate $P=TV$:

[image]

However, things seem more complicated for running:

[image]

Here, I'm not sure if the energy expenditure is due mainly to drag $D$, since $D$ for a runner ought to be much smaller than for a flyer. As a matter of fact, $V$ is quite lower, and $D$ is approximately proportional to $V^2$:

$$D=\frac 1 2 \rho_{air}C_D A V^2 $$

wher $C_D$ is the drag coefficient. On the other hand, the cross-sectional area $A$ is larger than for a flyer, and $D$ must be equal to the friction $F$ on the foot (which is obviously in the forward direction, since the foot pushes backward), if the runner is not accelerating horizontally.

However, there's something I don't understand: $D$ is doing work on the runner at a rate $P=DV$. However, the foot on the ground is at rest in the ground reference frame, otherwise the runner would slip.  This means that $F$ does no work on the runner! How can then the kinetic energy of the runner be approximately constant? Which other forces are doing work on the runner?

Comment: Yes drag is negligible. Can be ignored. Dont need that equation. There is not really friction to worry about either

Comment: @AlBrown You've obviously never run against the wind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, Frictional $F$ does no work on the runner in the ground frame.  Running is a more complex motion.

During the thrust phase of your step, the muscles in your leg are doing work on your moving torso.  ($F$ holds your foot still so this work can be done).  Then during the recovery phase, your leg muscles do work on your foot to lift and accelerate it ahead of your torso.

Unlike the airplane where much of the loss is in drag, the runner will also have losses due to the inelastic collisions with the ground.  Every step that lands will have vibrational/heat losses that are not recovered with the next step.  There's no simple "proportional to $v^2$" type equation that I'm aware of to estimate these biomechanical inelastic losses.

Comment: Ah right! Unlike linear momentum, kinetic energy can vary because of the work of internal forces. So even if the external forces only do zero () or even negative (, forces involved in inelastic collisions) work, the work of the internal forces can still suffice to keep my kinetic energy constant.

Answer (score 1):

In the last olympic marathon, everytime they showed the front runners in slow motion, it was clear that each step was also a small jump. The center of gravity oscillates about 10 to 20 cm I guess. So they have to do work to increase its gravity potential at each step.

Of course they "fall" just after, and by the same amount, but it doesn't help too much on their effort. But it helps a little, because the hard soil and the running sneakers give back some of the kinetic energy on the collision with the ground.

That is the reason why running barefoot in the sand is more tiresome. The collisions are inelastic, and the runner must do all work for each small jump.

About the birds, I think the same reasoning applies. Their CM fall and rise a little bit with the rhythm of their wings.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't think the cyclic variation of CM height would matter, because gravity is a conservative force and all the work done against it in the ascending phase, is compensated by the same amount of work done by gravity on me in the descending phase. But I forgot that the collisions with the ground are inelastic.

Comment: For what it regards birds, though, the effect is not nearly as important. As a matter of fact 1) there are no inelastic collisions here, so work done against gravity is nearly totally compensated by work done by gravity, except for a very small amount due to drag, 2) birds have hollow bones, so you don't need to do much work in order to move their CM up & down, 3) drag in the horizontal direction is obviously much larger than drag in the vertical direction. So for birds in level (on a cycle)  flight the effect is mostly negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the selected answer, which is good. But I think another fundamental aspect is still being unexpressed so far.

Let’s understand something simpler first: doing deep knee bends. If someone does deep knee bends all day, they expend a lot of energy. To focus further, let’s assume they don’t accelerate and decelerate that much - that the motions are relatively slow. Your muscles and gravity are both doing positive then negative work, alternatively. They cancel each other out. Even in running, this factor is larger and more important than inelastic collisions and friction, than heat and sound. By conservation of energy, it is coming from metabolism, which is the irreversible breaking of chemomechanical bonds that hold energy. So the metabolic potential energy inside the body is decreasing as energy is expended.

Another (ultimately equivalent) view is that the exerciser gets energy from metabolism, does positive work with it, increases his *cog* potential energy (by $mg \Delta h$) with the work, then gravity does negative work on him and lowers his *cog* potential energy, etc. Momentum is conserved by pushing off the earth on the way up, and by mutual gravitational attraction to the earth on the way down.

Now imagine energy expended by standing there with your arms straight above your head, and then lowering one arm while raising either leg (until maybe your elbow is about to touch your knee). This would take energy too, even if it was done in such a way as to keep the body’s *cog* at the same height. (Perhaps it’s not coincidence that this mimics the running motion). We are expending energy in an ongoing way, yet not increasing kinetic energy (in fact KE is back to zero after every rep), and not changing our potential energy of elevation.

So what’s going on? It would be hard to claim that all the energy is being dissipated to light and heat and sound energy via inelastic collision.

In running, the overall *cog* does go up and down a little, but even more so, parts of the body go up and down. Imagine pushing off the ground (conserving momentum) with one foot, the other leg goes up which takes work. Over the same time period, gravity does work to lower the torso. This is how work can be done on and by the body over the same duration and expend energy while not moving overall body *cog*.

The losses due to inelastic collision with the ground, friction with the ground, and wind resistance do not combine to take much of the energy expended. It’s not mostly friction or collision: Most of the reason we cannot just keep increasing kinetic energy is because our motion is largely up and down, and we spend a lot of the energy raising and lowering various parts of the body, working against gravity and being worked on by gravity, which largely balance out and keep energy level constant - despite our metabolism adding energy via work via muscles.

This is by far the biggest factor. Claudio’s answer is closer than the selected answer, but he doesn’t account for up-and-down motion of body *parts* that balance to not affect *cog*, and he talks a lot about collisions (which do matter but nowhere near as much as work by and against gravity).